# GMapRoute doesn't get the right route

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm trying to get the Planned route of flight by using GMapRoute.However,it doesn't get the right route when the flight fly across  International date line.
Can anyone offer some help for me.Thank you!

The image is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw7tS.png]

Comment: Can we see what you have done so far?

Comment: Pls look at my image